# How do I retrieve some of videos details (duration, date, views) from a playlist with YouTube API V3 in one pass

Tags: c#, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Hello SO folks and more specifically Google folks monitoring this tag per your support page.   I am working from .NET and **PlaylistItems.List**("snippet,contentDetails") does not do a whole lot compared to the old RSS Feed search.  In fact adding part **contentDetails** adds little value in that only the VideoID is now returned but it is already part of Snippet.ResourceId.VideoId

> "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
>      bla,
>      bla,
>      "contentDetails": {
>       "videoId": "DLME0PsJRnk"
>      }

Why add a "part" which is only going to return one bit of information?

How about supporting something like "snippet,contentDetails(**duration,PublishedAt,Views**)"
I feel this is kind of basic metadata (snippet) most apps would want to list to the users. 
While you are at it please please remove this non-sense of Java casing of parameters.  Why would you leak-out your language of choice into an API, that's really sad. Yes it is frustrating to keep checking whether I case-spelled them correctly.

Well, it looks like you are forcing "us" to build a list of VideoIds than turn around and make more API calls when I was doing it previously with fewer.
It also means, I will have to manage the 50 items max paging twice, once for the playlist if it is over 50 videos and then manage manually my list of VideosIds paging when I turn around to make Videos.List calls.

Let me know if I missed an All-In-One call type of API,  thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I have now working, let me know if there is a better way

```
        // 20150802
    public async Task<List<YouTubeInfo>> PlaylistVideosInfo(String PlaylistID)
    {
        var YoutubeService = YouTubeService();
        //
        List<YouTubeInfo> VideoInfos = new List<YouTubeInfo>();
        //
        var NextPageToken = "";
        while (NextPageToken != null)
        {
            // 
            var SearchListRequest = YoutubeService.PlaylistItems.List("snippet");
            SearchListRequest.PlaylistId = PlaylistID;
            SearchListRequest.MaxResults = 50;
            SearchListRequest.PageToken = NextPageToken;
            // Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified query term.
            var SearchListResponse = await SearchListRequest.ExecuteAsync();
            // Collect Video IDs from this page
            var VideoIDsBatch = new List<string>(); // batch Video detail search by 50 max
            foreach (var searchResult in SearchListResponse.Items)
            {
                VideoIDsBatch.Add(searchResult.Snippet.ResourceId.VideoId);                    
            }
            // Make API call for this batch  - expect a single page :(
            var VideoListRequest = YoutubeService.Videos.List("snippet,contentDetails");
            VideoListRequest.Id = String.Join(",", VideoIDsBatch); 
            VideoListRequest.MaxResults = 50;
            var VideoListResponse = await VideoListRequest.ExecuteAsync();
            // Collect each Video details
            foreach (var VideoResult in VideoListResponse.Items)
            {
                YouTubeInfoAdd(VideoInfos, VideoResult);
            }
            // request next page
            NextPageToken = SearchListResponse.NextPageToken;
        }
        // Return All Videos' detail
        return VideoInfos;
    }
```